# Batch script installation

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

i have written a simple batch for java installation

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%c in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v Java7FamilyVersion') do set java_version=%%c
if %java_version%==1.7.0_55 (goto end) else (goto install)

:end
exit

:install
msiexec.exe /I "%~DP0jre1.7.0_55.msi" /q /norestart /L "%windir%\log\Oracle_SUN_JAVA7_SE_Up55_DE_x86_0253_Install.log"
```

I would like to check if the version i want to install is already installed if yes installation should be skipped.
When Java is not installed at all then of course the registry key is missing and i get an error.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added quotations for string comparisons, default value for java_version, error catch, and simplified if statement.  Try this.

```
set "java_version=0"
for /f "tokens=3" %%C in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v Java7FamilyVersion 2^>nul') do set "java_version=%%C"
if not "%java_version%"=="1.7.0_55" goto install
exit

:install
msiexec.exe /I "%~DP0jre1.7.0_55.msi" /q /norestart /L "%windir%\log\Oracle_SUN_JAVA7_SE_Up55_DE_x86_0253_Install.log"
```

Comment: Thx, error catch is 2>nul and redirects the error to nul? Did i get this right? When i past the reg query command to cmd it works, no output when java is not installed, but when running the skript it says 2> cannot syntactically processed.

Comment: @KermitChristmas Correct.  `2>nul` sends the stderr stream (2) to a nul stream.

Comment: I can't find the exact wording in english of my error code because it's in other lang but on this part with 2>nul i get when running the script: "2>" can't syntactical be processed. When i past the command directly in cmd it does redirect the error

Comment: @KermitChristmas Sorry bout that, forgot to add the escape `^` for the redirect operator `>`. Updated the answer.